# Decoding hex scriptsig in Python

Tags: script, python, input-script

Running `decodescript` on `d1a076722d11ddfd0fadb96d6d960b8b2ad6c6369570cd00df70a801a6be9e44` is returning:

```
{
  "asm": "0 30440220278ee027abaf4720f580ce469139d75e330e120f91ff52b2c73955a712b96f3902204f11b7b1541dee5497cffd50291347b796e44ab1b6dac845d43a7185fdda184901 3045022100c3602c2872248e73f543fbf21ddc9fa3b73052261f619452fd5254852c9ea55102202c1323830f38a6fe149e0eccb18f92eba962165733285812deb96bcb8482de5d01 30450221008caaadf9b887828d02911ff22df335606c372f968d5c2ea0fa2f8c1a083fe5f502204c55eb85c0f06e10d488d7643a5c571bbabdeb935acc917836d44e755db6b1f601 532102939a016f9a4cfc4c73ba395c2baf16382a4de078dadf2bafaaac6846d786ed392102c7cf0bd62fb500d8f6ed39a46c7e72dc1b5185754e1a48d25a22195f113b35d8210306179c491a25d6db330a3a3e3ba0788b3ccea45aebfa2a06fc114787aadc01532103b8a79bd499afbc0f4b68e4c0e175176a013b1e2143da6ec95772add5c6728d6d2103bec7b18285d7af85b4f2c0936a106b746eaad14071f41788257fdffeb2e68e9a2103e4fda639ffcf2d996dc372db5eda18857afdd21054009d65ddd17ce96d5feed22103f5d1065abd2a8b5adc6ecda48712d2a572a24130b786f538629ff834b298379857ae",
  "type": "nonstandard",
  "p2sh": "32QZxW8qHSufifvr5UzXpzGG6jdcgnTCSF",
  "segwit": {
    "asm": "0 59d0d03149e611e8f8e879ab7c1133c99091ec09758ed29a9111341e424d9891",
    "hex": "002059d0d03149e611e8f8e879ab7c1133c99091ec09758ed29a9111341e424d9891",
    "reqSigs": 1,
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
    "addresses": [
      "bc1qt8gdqv2fucg7378g0x4hcyfnexgfrmqfwk8d9x53zy6pusjdnzgsdvlm7s"
    ],
    "p2sh-segwit": "36sk1CLrrv8HXgE1d1CKkNkwnK2tWKeWSL"
  }
}
```

The original Hex:

```
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
```

**Blockstream explorer is returning the script in form of OP_CODEs, my question is, is there any python library that can decode it to the same state?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two I'm aware of: [Python-bitcoinlib](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib) and [bitcoin_tools](https://github.com/sr-gi/bitcoin_tools)

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the libraries, and Peter Todd's one looks legit for this case, but all the methods there relates to script evaluation/serialization rather than to decoding the content of `decoderawtransaction` into SCRIPT. I am just confused on which method to use to get the result that's being shown by blockchain explorer.

Comment: Not sure what method you should use in Python-bitcoinlib. You can construct a transaction or script from hex in bitcoin_tools and call the deserialize to get that representation: https://github.com/sr-gi/bitcoin_tools/blob/master/bitcoin_tools/core/script.py#L54